# How can I use stock Android colors in layout file?

Tags: android, colors

I know how to define my own colors.xml file if needed, but is there a way to refer to the [stock Android colors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) by name from a layout xml file?

ie - android:background="black"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
android:background="@android:color/black"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely do that.

If you want to refer to the 'stock' Android colours from your layout xml file, just use @android:color/colour_name_here

For Example:

```
android:background="@android:color/black"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```